# Due to & in string , can't pass using JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am using this format to pass data to server in GET request .

```
var val = {
    name:"abcd",
    age="21"
}
var val2 = "test2" ;
http://server-name/getdata.htm?data=JSON.stringify(val)&data1=val2
```

.

This works fine but , when val.name is like "abcd&def"
the format of request gets distorted due to this "&"

What should I do ?

Comment: It does not look like it would work fine. Why are you putting JSON in a parameter (`data`)?

Comment: Note that your object initializer has an error, I'm assuming it's just a typo in the question (the `=` after `age` should be a `:`). I also strongly recommend **not** relying on the horror that is [automatic semicolon insertion](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9) (there should be a `;` after the closing `}` on the assignment). And of course, the last line of the "code" block isn't code at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What should I do ?

You should correctly encode the elements of the query string, using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) (that's a link to MDC, but the function is available in all browsers, not just Firefox).

You haven't shown actual code, but along these lines:

```
var link = "http://server-name/getdata.htm?data=" +
           encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(val)) +
           "&data1=" +
           encodeURIComponent(val2);
```

Technically, the more correct way would be to also encode the keys `data` and `data1`, like this:

```
var link = "http://server-name/getdata.htm?" +
           encodeURIComponent("data") + "=" +
           encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(val)) +
           "&" + encodeURIComponent("data1") + "=" +
           encodeURIComponent(val2);
```

...but when you're dealing with literal keys (as opposed to keys coming from strings you don't control), when you know the encoded form is identical to the original (which it is for `data` and `data1`), you can get away with not encoding the keys.